# Does every finite abelian $p$-group $G$ admit a local ring structure with residue field of the same rank as $G$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, finite-groups

**Problem.** Is every finite Abelian $p$-group $G$ isomorphic to the additive group of a local commutative ring $R$ whose residue field $R/{\mathbf m}$ has rank, equal to the rank of the group $G$?

Here $\mathbf m$ stands for the unique maximal ideal of the ring $R$.

The *rank* of a finite Abelian $p$-group $G$ is the number of factors in the (unique) decomposition of $G$ in the product of cyclic $p$-groups. The *rank* of a finite field $F$ is defined as the rank of its additive group (so, $F$ has cardinality $p^{rank(F)}$ for a prime number $p$, equal to the characteristic of $F$).

**Remark 1.** The answer to the problem is well-known if $G$ is elementary abelian (which means that each element of $G$ has order $p$). In this case $G$ is isomorphic to the additive group of a (Galois) field.

**Remark 2.**  It may happen that this problem has affirmative answer  with a standard construction of the multplication (using irreducible polynomials). In this case I would greatly appreciate a proper reference.

Comment: I guess what you mean by rank of $G$ is the dimension of $G/pG$ over the field on $p$ elements, which is also the minimal number of generators of $G$.

Comment: Can you please describe the standard construction you mentioned in remark 1. Thanks.

Comment: @YCor I added the definition of a rank.

Comment: @tj_ The (stanard) construction of a Galois field of cardinality $p^k$ is given in Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field#GF.28p2.29_for_an_odd_prime_p

Comment: It's not important here, but it's not true (as you say in your definition) that the decomposition of finite abelian groups as product of cyclic groups is unique, think of $Z/6Z$. Yet it's true for finite abelian $p$-groups.

Comment: @YCor I had in mind cyclic $p$-groups (and corrected this place). Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how is defined the rank of a field?

Comment: @Matematicos-Chibchas The rank $rank(F)$ of a finite field $F$ is defined as the rank of its additive group, i.e. $F$ has cardinality $p^{rank(F)}$ for some prime number $p$. It may happen that in the Field Theory this rank is called differently (for example, dimension)?

Comment: @Taras Banakh: Let me say that I find your behavoir very, very rude. In the original version of your question you said there seems to be a standard construction turning an arbitrary abelian p-group into a local ring. It was this general  construction, I asked for in a comment. Afterwards you changed your text simply saying there is a standard construction for elementary abelian p-groups (which is absolutely trivial). Then, you responded to my comment and refered to a Wiki 
article for the construction of finite fields. I know how finite fields are constructed. ...

Comment: ...  If you were true, you would have said, that you actually don't know such a construction for arbitrary abelian p-groups, instead of presenting that I asked a beginners question!

Comment: @tj_ Sorry, I had no intention to offend you. Very often, in mathematics, too, people have some illusions. So, I had an illusion that I know how to define a multiplication turning the abelian group into a local ring with high ranked residue field. And I was almost sure that it is true, so just wanted to find a reference in order to save time and not write a proof which (as I thought) should exist. When you asked about the construction I referred to Wiki having in mind that the argument should be similar to the standard one. So, this is a true story.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This won't be true if $G=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

If $G$ has a local ring structure with maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$, and quotient field $G/\mathfrak{m}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_4$, then $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2\cong\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ as an abelian group.

But this is impossible, since $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$ is a vector space over the residue field $G/\mathfrak{m}\cong\mathbb{F}_4$.

A similar argument shows that it's not true unless
$G\cong(\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z})^n$ for some $k$ and $n$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer (which was opposite to what I expected). Could you give me a reference to the fact that each group $(\mathbb Z/p^k\mathbb Z)^n$ is isomorphic to the additive group of a local ring whose residue field has cardinality $p^n$?

Comment: @TarasBanakh I'm not sure of a reference, but I think you can always find an unramified degree $n$ extension $\mathcal{O}$ of the $p$-adic integers $\mathbb{Z}_p$ and then take $G=\mathcal{O}/p^k\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Thank you. But I am not an algebraist, so am not very fluent in all these theories. Maybe one of these two papers contains a required reference? https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.rmjm/1250131150 and another one is R.Gilmer, Zero-divisors in commutative rings, Amer. Math. Monthly, 93:5 (1986) 382--387?

Comment: It seems that I have found a good reference in the book "Finite Commutative Rings and their Applictions" of G.Bini and F.Flamini (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235426680_Finite_Commutative_Rings_and_Their_Applications). Such rings are called Galois rings and are denoted by $G(p^k,r)$. So, thanks to all for the fruitful discussion.